# How can I set a parent element’s style based on its child’s attributes in CSS?

Tags: css

For example when input is disabled, parent element should have Black background otherwise White.

```
<div><input type="text" disabled="disabled" /></div>

div input[type="text", disabled="disabled"] {
    background: Black;
}
```

I want to style parent element instead of child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible using CSS.

It is possible with JavaScript though.

Comment: It's the right answer isn't it? Please tell me if you have a better solution. You made me curious...

Comment: No no your answer is absolutely True

Answer (score 3):

You can select this elements parent with css has selector;

For Example;

Lats say we have an div and div have inside to input element;

```css
.hasan-ablak {
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: green;
        }

.hasan-ablak:has(input:disabled) {
  background-color: orange;
}
.hasan-ablak:has(input:disabled) {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="hasan-ablak">
            <input type="text">
</div>
    
<div class="hasan-ablak">
  <input type="text" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no parent selector in CSS as of the latest version.

Comment: There should be, though, shouldn't there? I mean how easy would it be to do `input < div { background: black; }` ?

Comment: @JMC: indeed. Apparently it’s quite a challenge, performance-wise, to get such selectors to work (especially when you consider that they have to work every time JavaScript changes the DOM) — see http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors#comment_3940 and http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

Comment: @Paul so it's possible! Make an answer and put your link on that.

Comment: @Sadegh — ah, no, my links are just to discussion of why a parent selector *won’t* be implemented in CSS any time soon.