# in css3, can you set an element's style according to what it contains?

Tags: css

for example, if I wished to center the contents of a `TD` if it contained, or had firstChild of, `INPUT[type='checkbox']`

```
<style>
td ?? { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

do not see how it can be done.  believe impossible.  have been wrong before.

---

if `align` were still legal, one might have

```
td > input[type='checkbox'] { align: center; }
```

but don't think that's possible

Comment: Can you put a wrapper around the checkbox?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628905/how-can-i-set-a-parent-elements-style-based-on-its-childs-attributes-in-css

Comment: @Guido - yes it is.  but like @Knu's comment on `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called either ancestor or parent selector and won't be implemented because [selectors are unable to ascend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child/45530#45530).
As an alternative you will be able to achieve it using [$](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) which is currently not supported by the latest browsers.

Comment: had not seen the `$` - exactly what we need!  any idea if/when it's coming?

Comment: @young at the current rate I would say 2 years. In my dreams: yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing some time ago, and I found it is not possible to define that kind of "backreferences" in CSS.  It is not possible to define a CSS rule that takes into account inner childs to define the parent styles.

In your case, if you know in advance which cells are going to contain a checkbox, you should create a class:

```
td.centered {
  ...
}
```

and use that style in your markup:

```
<td class="centered">
    your checkbox here
</td>
```

Or you can do it with javascript after the table is rendered:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").parent("td").css(...);
```

To know some of the reasons, you can also take a look at [Why don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

Comment: you're right, but do a lot of dynamic forms, so something like this would make my life easier

Comment: With javascript you could, once your layout is rendered, find every checkbox -> find its parent -> apply the style.  I think jQuery has some methods that could help you : $("input[type='checkbox'").parent("td").css(...);

Comment: using jsrp - about a week from 0.1 release - `r.td('.c',r.checkbox('active'))` where `r` is a renderer and 'active' is a column name and 'c' is class name (that centers) - I think I'm the only person in the universe who doesn't use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Well, styling the parent by checking the properties of a child is not possible through CSS (I guess).

### Example

### HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    This is the parent.
    <div id="child">
        This is the child.
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

You can do this -

```
#parent > #child {
    color: red;
}
```

But this will give red color to `This is the child.` and not `This is the parent.`